# Application Error - Deploying Node JS on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

> "APPLICATION ERROR - An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application
>   owner, check your logs for details."

Hi guys - getting this *after* it's successfully built on Heroku

From other threads i gather this may be something to do with dependencies?

My code is using EJS, Express, Cheerio.

the Package.json looks like this - what am i doing wrong? :)

```
{
  "name": "node-ejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rainbow",
    "awkward"
  ],
  "author": "dsddfb",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "casperjs": "^1.1.1",
    "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
    "ejs": "^2.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "nodevine": "^1.0.1",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "request": "^2.72.0"
  }
}
```

My back-end/Server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

My Heroku logs don't seem to show much in the way of errors. Two lines are of concern though. PhantomJS and something saying NPM Config Error.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 3.8.6
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules

       > phantomjs@2.1.7 install /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs
       > node install.js

       PhantomJS not found on PATH
       Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1//phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
       Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
       Receiving...

       Received 22866K total.
       Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
       Removing /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
       Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1465892716753/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
-> /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
       Writing location.js file
       Done. Phantomjs binary available at /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
       casperjs@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/casperjs
       cheerio@0.20.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cheerio
       css-select@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/css-select
       boolbase@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/boolbase
       css-what@2.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/css-what
       domutils@1.5.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/domutils
       dom-serializer@0.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/dom-serializer
       domelementtype@1.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/dom-serializer/node_modules/domelementtype
       entities@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/entities
       domelementtype@1.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/domelementtype
       nth-check@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nth-check
       htmlparser2@3.8.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/htmlparser2
       domhandler@2.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/domhandler
       entities@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/htmlparser2/node_modules/entities
       readable-stream@1.1.14 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/readable-stream
       core-util-is@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/core-util-is
       inherits@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/inherits
       isarray@0.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/isarray
       string_decoder@0.10.31 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/string_decoder
       lodash@4.13.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/lodash
       ejs@2.4.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ejs
       express@4.13.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/express
       accepts@1.2.13 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/accepts
       mime-types@2.1.11 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.23.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/mime-db
       negotiator@0.5.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/negotiator
       array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/array-flatten
       content-disposition@0.5.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/content-disposition
       content-type@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/content-type
       cookie@0.1.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cookie
       cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cookie-signature
       debug@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/express/node_modules/debug
       ms@0.7.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ms
       depd@1.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/depd
       escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/escape-html
       etag@1.7.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/etag
       finalhandler@0.4.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/finalhandler
       debug@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/debug
       on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/on-finished
       ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ee-first
       unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/unpipe
       fresh@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/fresh
       merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/merge-descriptors
       methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/methods
       parseurl@1.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/parseurl
       path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/path-to-regexp
       proxy-addr@1.0.10 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/proxy-addr
       forwarded@0.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/forwarded
       ipaddr.js@1.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ipaddr.js
       qs@4.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs
       range-parser@1.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/range-parser
       send@0.13.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/send
       debug@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug
       destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/destroy
       http-errors@1.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/http-errors
       statuses@1.2.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/statuses
       mime@1.3.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/mime
       serve-static@1.10.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/serve-static
       send@0.13.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send
       debug@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/debug
       type-is@1.6.13 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/type-is
       media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/media-typer
       utils-merge@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/utils-merge
       vary@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vary
       nodevine@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine
       json-bigint@0.1.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/json-bigint
       bignumber.js@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/bignumber.js
       querystring@0.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/querystring
       request@2.72.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/request
       aws-sign2@0.6.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/aws-sign2
       aws4@1.4.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/aws4
       bl@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/bl
       readable-stream@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/readable-stream
       isarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/isarray
       process-nextick-args@1.0.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/process-nextick-args
       util-deprecate@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/util-deprecate
       caseless@0.11.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/caseless
       combined-stream@1.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/combined-stream
       delayed-stream@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/delayed-stream
       extend@3.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/extend
       forever-agent@0.6.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/forever-agent
       form-data@1.0.0-rc4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/form-data
       async@1.5.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/async
       mime-types@2.1.11 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/mime-types
       har-validator@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/har-validator
       chalk@1.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/chalk
       ansi-styles@2.2.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ansi-styles
       escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
       has-ansi@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/has-ansi
       ansi-regex@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ansi-regex
       strip-ansi@3.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/strip-ansi
       supports-color@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/supports-color
       commander@2.9.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/commander
       graceful-readlink@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/graceful-readlink
       is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/is-my-json-valid
       generate-function@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/generate-function
       generate-object-property@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/generate-object-property
       is-property@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/is-property
       jsonpointer@2.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jsonpointer
       xtend@4.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/xtend
       pinkie-promise@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/pinkie-promise
       pinkie@2.0.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/pinkie
       hawk@3.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/hawk
       boom@2.10.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/boom
       hoek@2.16.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/hoek
       cryptiles@2.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cryptiles
       sntp@1.0.9 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/sntp
       http-signature@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/http-signature
       assert-plus@0.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/assert-plus
       jsprim@1.2.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jsprim
       extsprintf@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/extsprintf
       json-schema@0.2.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/json-schema
       verror@1.3.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/verror
       sshpk@1.8.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/sshpk
       asn1@0.2.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/sshpk/node_modules/asn1
       assert-plus@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/sshpk/node_modules/assert-plus
       dashdash@1.13.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/dashdash
       assert-plus@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/dashdash/node_modules/assert-plus
       getpass@0.1.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/getpass
       assert-plus@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/getpass/node_modules/assert-plus
       is-typedarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/is-typedarray
       isstream@0.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/isstream
       json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/json-stringify-safe
       mime-types@2.1.11 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/mime-types
       node-uuid@1.4.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/node-uuid
       oauth-sign@0.8.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/oauth-sign
       qs@6.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nodevine/node_modules/qs
       stringstream@0.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/stringstream
       tough-cookie@2.2.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/tough-cookie
       tunnel-agent@0.4.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/tunnel-agent
       phantomjs@2.1.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs
       extract-zip@1.5.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/extract-zip
       concat-stream@1.5.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/concat-stream
       readable-stream@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream
       isarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/isarray
       typedarray@0.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/typedarray
       debug@0.7.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/debug
       mkdirp@0.5.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/mkdirp
       minimist@0.0.8 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/minimist
       yauzl@2.4.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/yauzl
       fd-slicer@1.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/fd-slicer
       pend@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/pend
       fs-extra@0.26.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/fs-extra
       graceful-fs@4.1.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/graceful-fs
       jsonfile@2.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jsonfile
       klaw@1.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/klaw
       path-is-absolute@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/path-is-absolute
       rimraf@2.5.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/rimraf
       glob@7.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/glob
       inflight@1.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/inflight
       once@1.3.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/once
       wrappy@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/wrappy
       minimatch@3.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/minimatch
       brace-expansion@1.1.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/brace-expansion
       balanced-match@0.4.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/balanced-match
       concat-map@0.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/concat-map
       hasha@2.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/hasha
       is-stream@1.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/is-stream
       kew@0.7.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/kew
       progress@1.1.8 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/progress
       request@2.67.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/request
       aws-sign2@0.6.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/aws-sign2
       bl@1.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/bl
       readable-stream@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/readable-stream
       isarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/isarray
       caseless@0.11.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/caseless
       extend@3.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/extend
       har-validator@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/har-validator
       hawk@3.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/hawk
       http-signature@1.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/http-signature
       assert-plus@0.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/assert-plus
       qs@5.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/qs
       request-progress@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/request-progress
       throttleit@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/throttleit
       which@1.2.9 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/which
       isexe@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/isexe
       request@2.72.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/request
       bl@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/bl
       readable-stream@2.0.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/bl/node_modules/readable-stream
       isarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/bl/node_modules/isarray
       qs@6.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/qs
       twit@2.2.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit
       bluebird@3.4.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/bluebird
       request@2.58.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/request
       aws-sign2@0.5.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/aws-sign2
       bl@0.9.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/bl
       readable-stream@1.0.34 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/readable-stream
       isarray@0.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/isarray
       caseless@0.10.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/caseless
       extend@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/extend
       har-validator@1.8.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/har-validator
       bluebird@2.10.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/bluebird
       hawk@2.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/hawk
       http-signature@0.11.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/http-signature
       asn1@0.1.11 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/asn1
       assert-plus@0.1.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/assert-plus
       ctype@0.5.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ctype
       mime-types@2.0.14 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.12.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/mime-db
       qs@3.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/twit/node_modules/qs
       vineapple@0.1.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple
       colors@0.6.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/colors
       lodash@1.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/lodash
       pkginfo@0.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/pkginfo
       q@0.9.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/q
       request@2.25.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/request
       aws-sign@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/aws-sign
       cookie-jar@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cookie-jar
       forever-agent@0.5.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/forever-agent
       form-data@0.1.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/form-data
       async@0.9.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/async
       combined-stream@0.0.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/combined-stream
       delayed-stream@0.0.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/delayed-stream
       mime@1.2.11 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/mime
       hawk@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/hawk
       boom@0.4.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/boom
       hoek@0.9.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/hoek
       cryptiles@0.2.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/cryptiles
       sntp@0.2.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/sntp
       http-signature@0.10.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/http-signature
       oauth-sign@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/oauth-sign
       qs@0.6.6 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/qs
       tunnel-agent@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/vineapple/node_modules/tunnel-agent
       abab@1.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/abab
       acorn-globals@1.0.9 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/acorn-globals
       acorn@2.7.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/acorn
       amdefine@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/amdefine
       casper@0.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/casper
       cssom@0.3.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cssom
       cssstyle@0.2.36 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/cssstyle
       deep-is@0.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/deep-is
       ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/ecc-jsbn
       jsbn@0.1.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jsbn
       estraverse@1.9.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/estraverse
       esutils@2.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/esutils
       fast-levenshtein@1.1.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/fast-levenshtein
       jodid25519@1.0.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jodid25519
       jsdom@7.2.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/jsdom
       escodegen@1.8.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/escodegen
       esprima@2.7.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/esprima
       optionator@0.8.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/optionator
       levn@0.3.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/levn
       prelude-ls@1.1.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/prelude-ls
       type-check@0.3.2 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/type-check
       wordwrap@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/wordwrap
       nwmatcher@1.3.7 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/nwmatcher
       parse5@1.5.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/parse5
       sax@1.2.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/sax
       symbol-tree@3.1.4 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/symbol-tree
       webidl-conversions@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/webidl-conversions
       whatwg-url-compat@0.6.5 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/whatwg-url-compat
       tr46@0.0.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/tr46
       xml-name-validator@2.0.1 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/xml-name-validator
       source-map@0.2.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/source-map
       tweetnacl@0.13.3 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300/node_modules/tweetnacl
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
       node-ejs@1.0.0 /tmp/build_a9be1f008d6086e09ea0b623aaf6c300
       ├── casper@0.1.1  extraneous
       └── request@2.72.0

-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
       ├── casperjs@1.1.1
       ├── cheerio@0.20.0
       ├── ejs@2.4.2
       ├── express@4.13.4
       ├── nodevine@1.0.1
       ├── phantomjs@2.1.7
       ├── request@2.72.0
       ├── twit@2.2.4
       └── vineapple@0.1.5

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 46.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://hidden-earth-83430.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying node version in your package.json as below and then try to deploy on heroku:

```
    "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "engines": {
       "node": "4.3.1"
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm... re-reployed to Heroku but still the same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Start real time logs in one CLI using `heroku logs -t --app <app name>`
And deploy from other CLI. You might get the proper error log in real time while your application is being deployed. Sometime the logs are skipped. Check if you get detailed error log.